# Why isn't my .hide() function working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been doing a lot of FreeCodeCamp and CodeCademy courses recently and finally decided to try to create my own webpage. I'm wondering why my code isn't working? Did I not src jQuery correctly? [The Code](https://imgur.com/a/4u8o3)[1]

Comment: Try putting your script tag on the end of your body tag, should be enough. Also always post your code as text instead of an image ;)

Comment: Post your code not an image!

Comment: Check the browser console and network tab.  I suspect there's an error that's trying to tell you the problem.

Comment: You can post your code on stack overflow or codepen like this [YOUR_CODE](http://codepen.io/andretw/pen/oYZogJ), it will be easier for everyone to help you. You just need to include the path correctly as the snippet or the other answers listed, you can get the right result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `https://` before `code.jquery.com` in your `<script>` tag. Like this: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>`

Comment: Thankyou! Geesh I was downvoted to oblivion. Probably going to be my first and last post lol. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Also, you were downvoted so hard because you attached your code as a link to an image. People on this site are very sensitive about etiquette. In future, make sure to copy and paste your code directly into the question so it's easy for others to read.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I shall become an etiquette abiding citizen from now on.

Comment: It's also etiquette to mark an answer as correct if/when you deem an answer to be the "right answer". ;)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: There should be a faded checkmark by each answer. If you click it, it will mark that answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry for the wait, but I selected your answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer said, put `https://` in front of your `src` in the script-call - or just use `//` which will work regardless of specific protocol.